# Cannot delete a file on server using ftp from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ftpwebrequest

I have created an asp.net application to maintain images for a shopping site, it includes 2 functions, one for uploading the image via ftp and the other for deleting the image using ftp.

I can upload files without an issue but when I try to delete a file I get the response "The remote server returned an error: (530) Not logged in."

I'm using the same ftpuri and credentials so I'm a little confused as to why it doesn't work.

Here's the code for the upload which works.

Upload Section :

```
    Dim ftpRequest As FtpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(ftpuri), FtpWebRequest)

    Try
        ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile

        ftpRequest.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(ftpusername, ftppassword)

        Dim bytes() As Byte = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filetoupload)

        ftpRequest.ContentLength = bytes.Length

        Using UploadStream As Stream = ftpRequest.GetRequestStream()
            UploadStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)
            UploadStream.Close()
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

---

Here's the code for the delete that fails with the error ***The remote server returned an error: (530) Not logged in.***

Delete Section:

```
   Dim ftpRequest As FtpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(ftpUri), FtpWebRequest)

    Try
        ftpRequest.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(ftpusername, ftppassword)

        ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile

        Dim responseFileDelete As FtpWebResponse = CType(ftpRequest.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

---

In both cases the values in ftpuri, ftpusername and ftppassword are identical.

I can delete the file using ftp software with the same credentials.

Any help would be appreciated.

Ron

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```
public bool DeleteFileFromFtpServer(Uri serverUri, string ftpUsername, string ftpPassword)
{
  try
   {
    // The serverUri should look like this ftp:// scheme.
    // It contains server name along with file name that will be deleted.
    // eg: ftp://abc.com/test.txt. 

    if (serverUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeFtp)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // Get the object used to communicate with the server.
    FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serverUri);
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUsername, ftpPassword);
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;

    FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();        
    response.Close();
    return true;
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
    {
      return false;
    }            
}
```

Calling:

```
obj.DeleteFileFromFtpServer(new Uri (toDelFilename), user,pass);
```